# Error on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I got an error in my wordpress site,like

```
Uname:
User:
Php:
Hdd:
Cwd:    Linux v9.cyberns.net 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 18:10:13 EDT 2011 x86_64 [Google] [milw0rm]
763 ( hclsecur ) Group: 760 ( hclsecur )
5.3.10 Safe mode: OFF [ phpinfo ] Datetime: 2012-03-12 06:05:02
1 B Free: B (0%)
u--------- [ home ]
    UTF-8Windows-1251KOI8-RKOI8-Ucp866
Server IP:
182.18.185.130
Client IP:
117.207.198.223
[ Sec. Info ]   [ Files ]   [ Console ] [ Sql ] [ Php ] [ Safe mode ]   [ String tools ]    [ Bruteforce ]  [ Network ] [ Self remove ]
File manager
Can't open this folder!
Change dir:

Read file:
Make dir:
[ Not writable ]    
Make file:
[ Not writable ]
Execute:

Upload file:
[ Not writable ]
```

I am new to wordpress so didn't get the real issue.. anybody please help

Comment: where did you get this error message?

Comment: Did you migrate the word press from anywhere? It seems like about some permission issue

Comment: No. i didn't migrate from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-can-someone-explain-me-what-has-been-done-of-my-website

This is the thing which you're looking for !!

Just try renaming the 'plugins' folder or/and try deleting and reuploading default wordpress templates, that's where the code generally resides for this stuff

Answer (score -1):

your site has been compromised, this is a php webshell backdoor.
l m g t f y dot c o m ! :@

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Sorry, posts can't contain that content.